# React - defaultProps vs ES6 default params when destructuring (performances issues)

Tags: performance, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I just came across a question about React performances when settings default values in one of my **stateless functional components**.

This component had a `defaultProps` which defined `row: false`, but I didn't like it because the `defaultProps` is **at the end** of the file, which actually makes it harder to see. And thus, we aren't aware of the default property. So I moved it to the function declaration directly and assigned it using ES6 default value for parameters.

```
const FormField = ({
  row = false,
  ...others,
}) => {
  // logic...
};
```

But then we argued with a coworker about this **being a good idea or not**. Because doing so may seem trivial, but may also have a great impact upon performances since **react is not aware** of the default value.

I believe in this case, it's trivial. Because it's a boolean and not an object/array and therefore won't be seen as a different value during *reconciliation*.

---

But, let's now see a more advanced use-case:

```
const FormField = ({
  input: { name, value, ...inputRest },
  label = capitalize(name),
  placeholder = label,
  row = false,
  meta: { touched, error, warning },
  ...others,
}) => {
  // logic...
};
```

Here, I base the value of `placeholder` from `label`, which itself is based on `input.name`. Using ES6 destructuring with default values for parameters makes the whole thing quite easy to write/understand and it works like a charm.

But is it a good idea? And if not, then how would you do it properly?

Comment: Personally, the argument list in `FormField` is too overloaded for my taste. If it's not immediately readable, it adds unnecessary complexity IMHO. I mean, you had to explain it. That said, defaulting certain incoming values is completely valid, Redux does this with its `initialState` object: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Comment: I agree it's getting heavy. Definitely the most complex I wrote so far, but it's clear enough IMO, thanks for the link, I'll take a look!

Comment: Cool, specifically the piece where he starts "One neat trick is to use the ES6 default arguments syntax..."

Comment: Yep. But this is for reducers, not for components. It's not the same lifecycle. It's great for reducers because it's just about the initial values. What I'm worried with the Components is because react may believe the value has changed somehow because it wasn't aware of the initial value, since it's never defined as props, but defined through default ES6 parameters.

Comment: But there is no lifecycle for stateless components, which is what your example is of.

Comment: I wasn't sure there was no lifecycle event for stateless components. I thought it was still related to React, because we still have `propTypes` for a stateless component, and those types are still checked by react. So I assume there may be other hidden things on the background that would be faster if the params where given through the props.

Comment: AFAIK, stateless components are React agnostic - they simply implement JSX to return a view: https://twitter.com/_chenglou/status/642854846941429760?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw It's a normal function.

Comment: Please update to `stateless functional components` from `stateless components`. It is more precise that way.

Comment: @prosti Done, thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I talked to several people on Discord #reactiflux channel and actually got the answer I was looking for.

There are basically three use-case with React components, and in some of them, *destructuring* params will impact performances so it is important to understand what's going on under the hood.

#### Stateless functional component

```
const MyComponent = ({ name = 'John Doe', displayName = humanize(name), address = helper.getDefaultAddress() }) => {
  return (
    <div>{displayName}</div>
  );
};
```

This is a stateless, functional component. There is no state, and it is functional because it is not a `Class` instance, but a simple function.

In this case, there is no life-cycle, you cannot have a `componentWillMount` or `shouldComponentUpdate` or `constructor` there. And because there is no management of the life-cycle, there is no impact on performances whatsoever. This code is perfectly valid. Some may prefer to handle the default `displayName` value within the function body, but in the end it doesn't really matter, it won't impact performances.

#### Stateless non-functional component

*(Do not do this!)*

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name = 'John Doe', displayName = humanize(name), address = helper.getDefaultAddress() } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>{displayName}</div>
          );
    }
}
```

This is a stateless non-functional component. There is no state, but it is not "functional" since it is a `class`. And because it is a class, extending `React.Component`, it means you will have a life-cycle. You can have `componentWillMount` or `shouldComponentUpdate` or `constructor` there.

And, because it has a life-cycle, the way of writing this component is **bad**. But why?

Simply put, React offers a `defaultProps` attribute, to deal with default props values. And it is actually better to use it when dealing with non-functional components, because it will be called by all methods that rely on `this.props`.

The previous code snippet creates new local variables named `name` and `displayName`, but **the default values are applied for this `render` method only!**. If you want the default values to be applied for every method, such as the ones from the React life-cycle (`shouldComponentUpdate`, etc.) then you **must** use the `defaultProps` instead.

So, the previous code is actually a mistake that may lead to misunderstanding about the default value of `name`.

Here is how it should be written instead, to get the same behavior:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name, displayName = humanize(name), address } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>{displayName}</div>
          );
    }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address: helper.getDefaultAddress(),
};
```

This is better. Because name will always be `John Doe` if it wasn't defined. `address` default value was also dealt with, but not `displayName`... Why?

Well, I haven't found a way around that special use-case yet. Because the `displayName` should be based on the `name` property, which we cannot access (AFAIK) when defining `defaultProps`. The only way I see is to deal with it in the `render` method directly. Maybe there is a better way.

We don't have this issue with the `address` property since it's not based on the MyComponent properties but rely on something totally independant which doesn't need the props.

#### Stateful non-functional component

It works exactly the same as "Stateless non-functional component". Because there is still a life-cycle the behavior will be the same. The fact that there is an additional internal `state` in the component won't change anything.

---

I hope this helps to understand when using destructuring with components. I really like the functional way, it's much cleaner IMHO (+1 for simplicity).

You may prefer to always use `defaultProps`, whether working with functional or non-functional components, it's also valid. (+1 for consistency)

Just be aware of the life-cycle with non-functional components which "requires" the use of `defaultProps`. But in the end the choice is always yours ;)

---

**Edit 10-2019**: defaultProps will eventually be removed from React API at some point in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443098/2391795 and https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/107 for the RFC.

Comment: I consider it a bad practice to hold props that can be derived from other props. `displayName` in only used when displayed (meaning, in the `render` function). That should be its scope.

Comment: That's a point of view. Also, my example may be considered a "bad practice" by some people, but in the end it may not be, depending on what you actually want to do. There probably are valid cases where props should be derivated from other props, my example just isn't.

Comment: Functional components still have lifecycles, but you can't access them. Also, you should use defaultProps on every component for consistency.

Comment: @Vadorequest Would love to see an update to this answer now that hooks were introduced to React.

Comment: Haven't followed that update, if someone with knowledge wants to edit my post, be welcome. :)

Comment: @LazarLjubenović https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443098/998919 tl;dr defaultProps will be deprecated for the new stateful functional components :)

Comment: Thanks @fgblomqvist I updated the answer to make this information more visible to future readers. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: This answer is not longer accurate since simple functions do have state and "lifecycle" via **hooks** and have become the standard instead of `Class`-based components

Comment: Because `defaultProps` and classes are deprecated in favour of functional components (w/o hooks), this answer isn't as useful as before. However, it's still accurate if you're using class-based components.

Answer (score 5):

One big difference between `defaultProps` and default function parameters is that the former will be checked against propTypes. The `require-default-props` rule of [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md) explains it very well.

> One advantage of `defaultProps` over custom default logic in your code is that `defaultProps` are resolved by React before the `PropTypes` typechecking happens, so typechecking will also apply to your `defaultProps`. The same also holds true for stateless functional components: default function parameters do not behave the same as `defaultProps` and thus using `defaultProps` is still preferred.

Comment: True. It's interesting to benefit from that feature when not using traditional JS. When using TS I don't care at all about PropTypes, as they duplicate warnings and config with TS itself. They both do a different job and not 100% identical, but my personal preference is to use TS over PropTypes checking and not use both.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the advanced use-case you have, you're adding unnecessary properties to the component. `label` and `placeholder` are dependent on other properties being passed in and in my opinion, should not be listed as a parameter of the component itself.

If I were trying to use `<FormField />` in my application and I needed to look to see what dependencies that specific component has, I would be a little bit confused as to why you're creating parameters that are based off of other parameters. I would move the `label` and `placeholder` into the function's body so it's **clear** they are not component dependencies but simply side effects.

As far as performance is concerned here, I'm not sure there would be a significant difference in either way. Stateless components don't really have a 'backing instance' that stateful components do, which means there isn't an in memory object keeping track of the component. I believe it's just a pure function of passing parameters in and returning the view.

On that same note.. adding the PropTypes will help with the type checking.

```
const FormField = ({
  input: { name, value, ...inputRest },
  row = false,
  meta: { touched, error, warning },
  ...others,
}) => {
  const label = capitalize(name),
  const placeholder = label,

  return (
    // logic
  );
};

FormField.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  meta: PropTypes.shape({
    touched: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    warning: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  row: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: You're right, but it's because I wanted to have the ability to have a `label`/`placeholder` not related to the `name` that I choose to build it that way. It's more flexible.

Comment: Sure, maybe it's a good idea to keep `label` and `placeholder` in the properties so it's override able but do the conditional checking in the body of the component. Too me this could be a bit more confusing than just reading the required parameters and reacting accordingly. In the end, this does work and I don't think it would take a hit on react's performance on how it treats this function.