# Default Props in stateful (using hooks) functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I went through several questions on SO regarding default props for functional components and they all recommend using ES6 default parameters. Here are links to those questions.

- [React - defaultProps vs ES6 default params when destructuring (performances issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488537/react-defaultprops-vs-es6-default-params-when-destructuring-performances-issu)
- [React functional component default props vs default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774695/react-functional-component-default-props-vs-default-parameters)

---

However, when I use that method for writing components with effects running on props change, I get unwanted behaviour with non-primitives. For example, the following code will result in an infinite loop.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  let somethingUndefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Child prop={somethingUndefined} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ prop = {a: 1} }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [prop]);

  return <div>{x}, {prop.a}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

I attempted two ways of attempting to circumvent the issue. First, by just assigning a different variable that contains the default, and putting the unmodified prop in the dependency array. ie

```
const Child = ({ prop }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  const defaultedProp = prop || {a: 1};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [prop]);
  // Note we use prop and not defaultedProp here to avoid runnning into the issue above.

  return <div>{x}, {defaultedProp.a}</div>;
};
```

Another method would be to just use something like `(prop || {a:1})` in place of `prop` everywhere you use it, except in the dependency array. ie

```
const Child = ({ prop }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [prop]);

  return <div>{x}, {(prop || {a: 1}).a}</div>;
};
```

---

But both of these solutions seem suboptimal since it would require a lot of wasted effort (and bulky code).

`defaultProps` is also a solution to the infinite loop issue but it is [deprecated](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/createlement-rfc/text/0000-create-element-changes.md). Note that the example provided in this rfc also uses ES6 default parameters in the code.

**Am I missing something? Is there a better way to use default props in stateful functional components that run effects on props change?**

Comment: Why not pass default props directly from parent itself?

Comment: @Then that would be the default behaviour for the `Parent` component. We would want the `Child` component to have these defaults (Since a child component would most likely be reusable and need the same set of defaults everywhere).

Comment: Long live `defaultProps`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know whether this is eligible for an answer but all your concerns could be resolved by declaring your default value as a constant in the app. That means;

```
const Parent = () => {
  const somethingUndefined;

  return (
    <>
      <Child prop={somethingUndefined} />
    </>
  );
};

const Child = ({ prop = {a: 1} }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [prop]);

  return <div>{x}, {prop.a}</div>;
};
```

You can change the above code to

```
const Parent = () => {
  const somethingUndefined;

  return (
    <>
      <Child prop={somethingUndefined} />
    </>
  );
};

const defaultPropValue = {a: 1};

const Child = ({ prop = defaultPropValue }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [prop]);

  return <div>{x}, {prop.a}</div>;
};
```

This will not cause any infinite loops.

The difference bet these two:- In the first, the `prop` is initialized to a new value ie, `{a: 1}` and on every state update, this will be a new object (the new object will be in a new memory location), and it invokes the callback again.

In the second, we initialized and assigned the `{a: 1}` to `defaultPropValue` which will not change. Then we assigned this `defaultPropValue` to `prop` so that on every re-render, the value assigned to the `prop` will be the same ( or from the same memory location). So it works as expected.

Hope the idea is clear!

Comment: This works as well as I can hope for I suppose. It's still fairly tedious, since you have to define some like `childDefaults` for every stateful functional component that needs to have a default (which is all of them if you want a robust app). But this seems to be the best solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect()` will run the first time and invoke the `setX()` then:

- `setX()` will update the state of `x` which will trigger the component to re-render again.
- `prop` will receive a new object `const Child = ({ prop = {a: 1} }) => {`
- `useEffect()` will run again and invoke the `setX()`

the whole process repeats again, This causes an infinite loop.

Instead you could pass a default value to `a` property and use it in the `useEffect()` dependencies array

```js
const Parent = () => {
  let somethingUndefined; // babel complains if we use `const` without value

  return (
    <div>
      <Child prop={somethingUndefined} />      
      <Child prop={{ a: 3 }} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ prop = {} }) => {
  const { a = 1 } = prop;
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(x + 1);
  }, [a]);

  return <div>{x}, {a}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I realised the re-instantiation of the object was causing the loop. However, Your solution is basically the same as putting `prop.a` in the dependencies or writing `const {a = 1} = prop;`. Which can get very tedious, since in a real world situation you would end up having to list out every primitive in the object that is subject to change.

Answer (score -1):

See https://codepen.io/McKabue/pen/dyPxGLQ?editors=0010

```
const Parent = () => {
  const somethingUndefined = undefined;

  return <Child prop={somethingUndefined}/>;
};

const Child = ({ prop = {a: 1} }) => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setX(prop.a + 1);
  });

  return <div>{x}, {prop.a}</div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
useEffect(() => {
// anything you want to do
, [JSON.stringify(dependencyName)]}
```

Comment: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) `JSON.stringify` does not preserve key order within an object. This would mean that you could potentially get an infinite loop since the string would keep changing due to different key orders.

Comment: Yes thats true, in that case you can destructure your object and save the specific key in a variable for which you want to take the effect, and add that variable into the dependency

Comment: That would work, with the assumption that the value of that key would be a primitive. But if that were the case the bug would not exist in the first place. That is, I could just as easily right `useEffect(()=> {}, [prop.a])` since it would be equally effective in preventing the bug as writing `useEffect(()=> {}, [JSON.stringify(prop.a)])`. The problem occurs when the dependency needs to be a non-primitive value, in which case the above solution could possibly still cause an infinite loop.